# Trying to redirect paths with nginx using not in regex

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I want to redirect using nginx and append `/w` in front of the path, only in case specific paths are not matched, else all should work as supposed to.
This configuration is working:

```
location ~ ^/(?!(blog|w|images|reset_password)) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/w/$1 redirect;
}
```

But I need to include `/` in this regex.

Right now `/` is also being redirected to `/w` which should not happen.

Is there a way I can add root path in this regex so that it also does not get redirected and only other URLs should be redirected?

Comment: Probably simplest to add a rule for `location = /`, [reference](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#location_priority). Why is the rewrite inside a location block?

Comment: I have already tried this. Not working for my scenario. For rewrite inside location block: I need to run rewire for only these scenarios or paths.

Comment: `I have already tried this.` - I suspect not, see the linked reference - specifically this: 'If the exact match is found, the search stops.'. Note the first parameter for rewrite is a regex. You'll likely find things less confusing to use a positive match (i.e. `location = /`, `location ^/(blog|w|images|reset_password)` or any equivalent positive prefix match and the current logic in the question here: `location / { rewrite...`)